# Passar elemento HTML em variavel Jade

Tags: html, jade

Abaixo tenho uma chamada de um include para um “alert”, gostaria de saber se é possível dentro da variável mensagem não passar HTML puro () e sim uma chamada #[strong Bem feito!] que é mais comum dentro do pre-processador Jade.

```
- var type = 'success'
- var message = '<strong>Bem feito!</strong> Você lê com sucesso esta mensagem de alerta importante.'

div(class='alert alert-#{type} alert-dismissible', role='alert')
  button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='alert')
    span(aria-hidden='true') &#215;
    span.sr-only Fechar
  != message
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução que me ocorre é fazer dessa `message` uma array e usar assim:

```
- var type = 'success'
- var message = ['Bem feito!', 'Você lê com sucesso esta mensagem de alerta importante.']

div(class='alert alert-#{type} alert-dismissible', role='alert')
    button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='alert')
        span(aria-hidden='true') &#215;
        span.sr-only Fechar
    strong #{message[0]}#{' '}
    | #{message[1]}
```

Desta maneira chama o `'Bem feito!'` dentro do **strong** e o resto fora. O HTML fica assim:

```
<div role="alert" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="alert" class="close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&#215;</span><span class="sr-only">Fechar</span>
    </button>
    <strong>Bem feito! </strong>Você lê com sucesso esta mensagem de alerta importante.
</div>
```

Comment: Não é exatamente isso que preciso, porém é uma solução. Obrigado!

Comment: @BrunoBatista pode/quer fazer uma nova pergunta especificando melhor o que procura?

Comment: Não precisa @Sergio, caso consiga char a solução que desejo eu posto aqui, mas no momento essa solução me antede. Obrigado.